Displaying cards next to each other in 3,3 grid view and spacing between them
I was creating a movie information design where information about movies is shown in a card design I was trying to create 9 such cards where they are arranged 3 columns per row but it is displaying in a stack like structure and not in a 3,3 grid view and i could not get perfect spacing between them I did this with react bootstrap Here is the image of how it looks

//import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import movie1 from './images/movie1.jpg';
import movie2 from './images/movie2.jpg';
import movie3 from './images/movie3.jpg';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {Container, Row, Col, Card} from 'react-bootstrap';

function App() {
  return (
  
    <>
    <Container  fluid style={{marginTop: "20px" ,backgroundColor: "lightblue", display: "flex", justifyContent: "center"}}>
<div classNameName="row row-cols-3 gy-2">
  <div classNameName="col col-sm">
   <div className="card" style={{width: '15rem'}}>
  <img src= {movie1} className="card-img-top" alt="Movie"/>
  <div className="card-body">
    <h5 className="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p className="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
  <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li className="list-group-item">An item</li>
    <li className="list-group-item">A second item</li>
    <li className="list-group-item">A third item</li>
  </ul>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div classNameName="col">
   <div className="card" style={{width: '15rem'}}>
  <img src= {movie1} className="card-img-top" alt="Movie"/>
  <div className="card-body">
    <h5 className="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p className="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
  <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li className="list-group-item">An item</li>
    <li className="list-group-item">A second item</li>
    <li className="list-group-item">A third item</li>
  </ul>
   </div>
 </div>



</div>
</Container>
</>

 );
}

export default App;

I tried to change the display to flex and tried to justify the content but it did not change I also tried to add row and row-cols-3 and gx and gy for gutter class but still it remained the same as shown in image


You are using there classNameName somewhere instead of className
You can already use components Row and Col that you are importing instead of divs
Put the movies into array so you have something like const movies = [movie1, movie2, ...]
Then the correct code of what you trying to achieve will be something like this:

 <Container fluid style={{ marginTop: "20px", backgroundColor: "lightblue" }}>
      <Row className="gy-4">
        {movies.map((movie, index) => (
          <Col sm={12} md={6} lg={4} key={index}>
            <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
              <Card.Img variant="top" src={movie} alt={`Movie ${index + 1}`} />
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>Card title {index + 1}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                </Card.Text>
              </Card.Body>
              <Card.Footer>
                <small className="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
              </Card.Footer>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
  </Container> 


Wherever you are mapping to more complex structure like this you probably want to do a component named MovieCard and simplify the complexity of the code / making it more reusable.


what about the spacing between the columns and rows I tried using gutter class but it does not work in the display??

You can control the gap with either horizontal or vertical settings e.g. like this:
<Row className="gx-4 gy-4"> The gx-4 class sets horizontal gutters (spacing between columns), and the gy-4 class sets vertical gutters (spacing between rows).
